# Why lombok doesn't create getter?

Tags: getter, builder, lombok

I imported a project that use lombok to decrease code, but I got error "The method getBooks() is undefined for the type Author", where Book and Author are two entities.

```
this.getBooks().add(book);
book.setAuthor(this);
```

The Book Class used such anootations, and I also got warning "The type Builder is deprecated", how can I solve this problems?

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id")
@ApiObject(name = "Book", group = DocumentationConstants.GROUP_LIBRARY,   description = "Represents a book. Every book has an <code>Author</code> and a price.")
public class Book {
...
}
```

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I am using eclipse, now I got it after run java -jar lombok.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the problem regarding getBooks, but to solve the deprecation warning, you probably should replace the import from `lombok.experimental.Builder` to `lombok.Builder`

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.